# Make shapes snap to other shapes with KineticJS

Tags: kineticjs

Let's say I already dragged and dropped a rectangle in a container. How to make other draggable rectangles snap to the existing rectangle (to its **borders** not inside of it) in the canvas, in a way that's similar to jqueryUI implementation?

Comment: Can you provide demo of jqueryUI that you mean?

Comment: this jsfiddle is full of bugs, but there you will find a demo of the snap between rectangles http://jsfiddle.net/wQ8YA/22/ (drag and drop two rectangles and once dropped, drag them next to each other)

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to

Answer (score 2):

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/rx8SM/

Assuming you have a grid defined like this:

```
var cellWidth=40;
var cellHeight=40;
```

Then you can to snap to a cell intersection like this:

**Snap to the Top-Left intersection that the rectangle's x,y is in**

```
rect1.on("dragend",function(){

    // snap to the grid intersection that this rect's x,y is in

    var snapX=parseInt(this.x())/cellWidth)*cellWidth;

    var snapY=parseInt(this.y())/cellHeight)*cellHeight;

    this.position({x:snapX,y:snapY});

    layer.draw();
});
```

**Snap to the nearest Top-Left intersection**

```
rect1.on("dragend",function(){

    // snap to the closest top-left grid intersection

    var snapX=parseInt((this.x()+grid.cellWidth/2)/grid.cellWidth)*grid.cellWidth;

    var snapY=parseInt((this.y()+grid.cellHeight/2)/grid.cellHeight)*grid.cellHeight;

    this.position({x:snapX,y:snapY});

    layer.draw();
});
```

Comment: This is a bit far from what I need, I'll try to adapt it to my solution.

Comment: How to make it snap to the borders of the grid's rectangles, and not to the intersections only?